# Dimension to log on WebRTC connection

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc

I'm building a WebRTC app using Muaz Khan's [RTCMultiConnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection) library. In the application an initiator can share its screen to multiple users on a local network, where the maximum number of connected users will be 50-60.

I have an opportunity to test my app in a university PC room on 50 PCs and i want to log any necessary statistics during this test. However i'm not sure which metrics are the most important.

I already log peers' framerate and jitter on the initiator side. I think clients' video bitrate, video bitrate and bandwidth would be useful too, but currently i have not implemented logging functions for these.

In your experience what other ways exist to measure the quality of the connection and the video?